# Subtracting value across multiple lists in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am attempting to perform a simple subtraction function across two lists in Sharepoint 2010.

I have one list called Inventory that has part number, part name, and quantity.

I have a second list called Tasks that has title, description, status, used part, and quantity.

I have a workflow rule that states the following:

[image]

The issue is that it's just throwing an error when I run a test task with a status of completed, used part selected, and quantity field holding an integer value.

I am creating the workflow and attached it to the Tasks lists, so all current item equal items in the tasks.

The end of update item in Inventory I am setting the variable New Inventory to be the new value of quantity in the Inventory lists.

[image]

Any help with this would be great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Disregard, found out during the CurrentItem: Quantity lookup i had set the part name to string instead of lookup value.